# What is the correct way to update an ALAssetsLibrary when foregrounding a photo app?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios5, alassetslibrary

I have been struggling for some time with this one: how does a photo/video app that relies on `ALAssetsLibrary` keep the library in sync with the on disk library. Specifically, when re-foregrounding the app after it was backgrounded to allow some photos/videos to be shot/reorganized/deleted.

In my case it is complicated by the fact when my app is foregrounded I can be deep in a `UITableView` drill down using one of the assets from the library.

Thanks,
Doug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should register for ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification and only reenumerate the Library, when you receive the notification, that the Library has actually changed. You will receive this notification, when you app is in the foreground again. 
In detail it means you need to remunerate the assetsgroups and then the Alassets in the currently presented group in your application. 
Please note that, there is a bug in iOS 5.X regarding ALAssetsLibraryChangedNotification: http://www.openradar.me/10484334

Cheers,

Hendrik